# all but GUI is black

Tags: graphics, screen, gui, games

whenever i play a video game that has 3d graphics all i can see is the GUI and none of the actual rendered world... note: i'm a noob and just installed Ubuntu yesterday.

file:///home/lucas/Desktop/Screenshot.png -this is what the guild wars home screen looks like...

I have a toshiba satalite A135 with just a regular onboard intel graphics card. i played guild wars a lot when i had windows

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please upload the screenshot so we can see it. It is in your local drive!

Comment: Save it on http://imgur.com

Comment: @Tim very unlikely that he will respond - look at the date and when he was seen last :-))

Answer (score 1):

Have you activated proprietary drivers for your graphics card ?

Settings - additional drivers - are the driver for your card activated if not, then most likely you won't have 3d support so go turn it on  ;)

Edit:
file:///home/lucas/Desktop/Screenshot.png - this is a local link - people in here won't be able to see that. If you want to show pictures, then upload it on the web, and link to it here ;)